# Google apps script OnSelectionChange(e)

Tags: google-apps-script

I need a code on a Google Sheet doc that copies the value of column A to the lastrow of either column E or F depending on which column is selected.

[example of sheet data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0maI.png)

[image]

If I would take the example as shown in the image and I click on cell B4 'John' should be copied to E2 (which is the first available blank cell for the corresponding Task). If I click afterwards on B6 and C6 the final outcome should be as shown on the next image. [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ2Bc.png)

[image]

I want this code to be triggered everytime a click is made in columns B and C

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  //Logger.log(e);
  //Logger.log('%s!%s',e.range.getSheet().getName(),e.range.getA1Notation());
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    let col = e.range.getColumn();
    let row = e.range.getRow();
    //Logger.log('row: %s, col: %s',row,col);
    if (col > 1 && col < 4 && row > 1) {
      let [n, t1, t2] = sh.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3).getValues().flat();
      //Logger.log('t1: %s, t2: %s, name: %s',t1,t2,n);
      let h5 = getColumnHeight(5, sh, e.source);
      let h6 = getColumnHeight(6, sh, e.source)
      if (t1 == "Yes" && t2 == "No") {
        //e.source.toast("Gate2");
        sh.getRange(h5 + 1, 5).setValue(n);
      } else if (t1 == "No" && t2 == "Yes") {
        //e.source.toast("Gate3");
        sh.getRange(h6 + 1, 6).setValue(n)
      } else {
        //e.source.toast("Gate4");
        sh.getRange(h5 + 1, 5).setValue(n);
        sh.getRange(h6 + 1, 6).setValue(n);
      }
    }
  }
}

function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
  //const h = Utilities.formatString('col: %s len: %s', col, rcA.length - s);
  //Logger.log(h);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(h).setWidth(150).setHeight(100), 'Col Length')
}
```

Demo:

[image]